# Pushing an array to a session variable without re-instantiating the variable

Tags: php

I'm creating an `$item` array that I'd like to push to `$_SESSION['cart']`. After constructing my `item` array, I am trying:

`$_SESSION['cart'][] = $item[$item_id];`

Referencing:
[Can I use array_push on a SESSION array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616540/can-i-use-array-push-on-a-session-array-in-php)

However, my cart session variable keeps getting overwritten, rather than added to. Any other suggestions?

As requested from Mark:

First time being run:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\domain\store\cart.php on line 5
NULL array(3) { ["title"]=> string(37) "PA State and Federal Laminated Poster" ["price"]=> string(5) "55.95" ["qty"]=> string(1) "3" }
```

Second time:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\domain\store\cart.php on line 5
NULL array(3) { ["title"]=> string(53) "PA State and Federal Laminated Poster SPANISH Edition" ["price"]=> string(5) "55.95" ["qty"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Comment: Can you provide a `var_dump()` of before & after?

Comment: Do you call `session_start()` before `$_SESSION['cart'][] = $item[$item_id];`? The `notice` indicates that you don't.

Comment: That was it. Could you add this as an answer so I can assign points? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `session_start()` before you reference `$_SESSION`. The output you posted indicates you don't do that.

> Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\domain\store\cart.php on line 5